# US corporate bonds index

Tags: bonds

Does a US corporate bonds index exist? It should be free to access or accessible through Bloomberg or Reuters terminals.

Answer (score 2):

A quick google of "US Corporate Bonds Index" yields this: http://www.bloomberg.com/markets/rates-bonds/corporate-bonds/